# Python circular relative imports working in python 3 but not python 2

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, import, circular-dependency

This works in python 3 but emits an ImportError in python 2 (version 2.7):

Shell command:

```
$> python main.py
```

main.py

```
import mymodule

mymodule.KlassX().talk_klass_y()
mymodule.KlassY().talk_klass_x()
```

mymodule/__init__.py

```
from .x import KlassX
from .y import KlassY
```

mymodule/x.py

```
from . import y  # circular import

def KlassX:
    def talk(self):
        print('Im in KlassX')

    def talk_klass_y(self):
        y.KlassY().talk()
```

mymodule/y.py

```
from . import x  # circular import

def KlassY:
    def talk(self):
        print('Im in KlassY')

    def talk_klass_x(self):
        x.KlassX().talk()
```

As you may have noticed, I have written circular imports as relative imports since it is the recommended thing to do for imports inside a package ([PEP-0328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)).

I also tried to do absolute imports:

```
from mymodule import y  # in mymodule/x.py
from mymodule import x  # in mymodule/y.py
```

but this only still works for python 3 and not for python 2 (because of the same ImportError).

The only way that I can make it work in python 2 is using relative imports with the following unrecommended notation:

```
import y  # in mymodule/x.py
import x  # in mymodule/y.py
```

I really dislike it because "import somemodule" as a relative import only works in python 2 because in python 3 it is always forced to be an absolute import.
And I don't understand why this notations:

```
from mymodule import x
# or
from . import x
```

which are accepted in both python 2 and 3, behave different.

Any clue?
How should I correctly do the circular import in python 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the brief summary: https://gist.github.com/datagrok/40bf84d5870c41a77dc6

Comment: I see! The problem is with python 2 that does not work as expected, so I will have to stick with `import x`...